# IntelliJ MacOS Key for rerun is mapped differently in editor view

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anybody know why the keyboard shortcut in MacOS for IntelliJ to rerun (Command R) has a different effect in the editor view? There it opens the search.

I'm using IntelliJ 212.5457.

Thanks and best regards,
Theo

Answer (score 0):

Tool windows and Editor are different contexts, so the same shortcuts might trigger different actions depending on the component they were pressed in. Some actions available for the corresponding component can be found in the context menu together with the shortcuts.

If you find any shortcuts confusing, you can reassign them in the IDE Preferences | Keymap.